# Linq to Sql isnull in where clause not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Linq query as:

```
var notstartedcount = (from te in context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluations
                       join tesrt in context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluationStatusesRefTables
                       on te.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID equals 
                          tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID
                       where tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID.Equals("1") || 
                             tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID.Equals("")
                       select te).Count();
```

I just wanted to put `Isnull(ColumnName,replacement)` in where condition as we do it in Sql.

Eg.:

```
where isNull(EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID,0)=1
```

I kept same condition for linq as:

```
var notstartedcount = (from te in context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluations
                       join tesrt in context.EH_PP_TeacherEvaluationStatusesRefTables
                       on te.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID equals 
                          tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID
                       where 
                           isnull(tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID.Equals(Null),0).Equals("1") || 
                           tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID.Equals("")
                       select te).Count();
```

But its error in case of linq.

How can i put that condition into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the coalesce `??` operator

where

```
(tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID  ?? 0) == 1
```

or if it's a string (not really clear with your code)

```
(tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID  ?? "0") == "1"
```

But with the sample code given, this seem to be useless (the first version should do the same).

If what you mean is

> take all values where tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID IS NULL or
>   tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID == 1

then

```
tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID == null || tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID == 1
```

or

```
tesrt.EH_PP_TESRT_TeacherEvalStatusID ?? 1 == 1
```